# What does "package" mean in DNF software package manager?

Tags: fedora, package-management, dnf

I would like to know what does word "package" mean in DNF software package manager?
I would like to know:

1. What package is?
2. What are its characteristics?
3. What is it used for?
4. What are its alternatives?

All those questions are in the context of DNF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DNF package manager is successor of the YUM and is used in the Fedora distribution (and maybe some other). It works with repositories and helps, with solving RPM package dependencies.

The package in the Fedora context is RPM package. The RPM package provides set of files and metadata (description what the RPM package provides/requires, packager, build date/machine etc.). One RPM can provide one project or it's part or can provide files which are reqired by many other projects (like shared libraries).

You can study more for example on the wiki:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpm_(software)

if you're more interested, I recommend the RPM Maximum:

http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/index.html

Regarding alternatives. There used to be apt-rpm, providing apt-get style of package management known from Debian/Ubuntu. It was popular around 2000-2002, but RH decided to use YUM, which become official solution of RPM "dependency hell". I'm not aware of apt-rpm usability in scale of YUM/DNF these days.

Comment: Thank you very much. I don't know why but it was just hard for me to find the meaning of package in that context.